# Missing plugin SplashScreen in iOS with Ionic Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic6

I have an Ionic web/iOS application wherein I recently updated my code versions (ng10 to ng12 and minor bumps within Ionic 6) and the splash screen no longer hides. I did some looking and found that the plugin is not there, i.e. it's not available in X-code in the plug-ins list.  I've tried adding removing the plugins, adding removing the ios platform entirely and switching from @ionic/native to @awesome-cordova-plugins and the plugin never loads in X-Code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Splashscreen plugin is deprecated in version 6 of the related cordova-plugin-splashscreen. Blink and you'll miss it, but the indication is here [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#:~:text=cordova%2Dplugin%2Dsplashscreen%405-,If,-using%20cordova%2Dios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#:%7E:text=cordova%2Dplugin%2Dsplashscreen%405-,If,-using%20cordova%2Dios).

I wrapped the `splashscreen.hide()` call in a conditional to skip this for iOS and the problem was solved.

I also updated the config to auto-hide the splashscreen using preferences.